# Maximum Rank Correlation for panel data

Tags: regression, estimation, econometrics

Let $Z=(Y, X)$ be an observation from a distribution $P$ where $Y$ is a response variable and $X$ is a vector of regressors. Assuming the following model:
$Y = F(X'\beta, u)$ where $X'\beta$ is a linear index, $u$ is a random disturbance ($u \perp X$) and $F$ is a strictly increasing function in each of its arguments. We know that if $Z_i$ is a sample of independent observations from $P$, then we can estimate $\beta$ by simply maximizing the Rank Correlation (Han, 1986) between $Y$ and $X'\beta$.

QUESTION: would the same result apply for panel data (e.g., $Y_{ij}$ is the rank of item $j$ for the observation $i$ and there are $j=1,2,..., n$ items for each $i$)?

Comment: The way I would proceed is to assume that there are $F_i$ that can be different across $i$ units, and to impose the restriction that $\beta_i = \beta$. Then I would simply find the vector of $\hat\beta$ that would max the RC summed over units. Would this make sense?